# Java Heap Space Error when refactoring and initializing hg cache in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, refactoring, heap-memory

When I tried to delete a project in Eclipse I got the error below. Has anyone ever been in this situation?

[image: Error]

I've seen several questions relating to heap space, which suggest re-allocating memory in eclipse.ini but I would like to refrain from this as much as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you're not going to avoid it.  Java apps such as eclipse take as much RAM as they need and blow up if they don't get it.  You can always increase the heap, relaunch, do the action you want, and then revert the RAM allocation and relaunch again.

The heap allowed (-Xmx) is a max, so your JVM is only grow that big if it needs it, but it never gives it back without restarting the JVM.